# Magento Store View - Incorrect Currency Displayed

Tags: magento, view, store

I've gone through and set up an additional store view for our Magento store. The purpose of this view is to allow the display of different currency (for now) with future plans to allow language, content, etc based on store view.

Everything seems pretty normal. When I go to www.example.com/au - I get the standard version of the site with $AU as the currency.

When I navigate to www.example.com/us - The proper currency conversion is happening, showing in $US, but only in the mini-cart and checkout. The category and product view pages are still displaying the $AU value.

Those template files were completed by a different developer, and so I'm assuming they used the wrong function to grab the price of each item. They used:

```
<?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2) ?>
```

I'm thinking I need to toss in the proper function that grabs the price based on store view id, but I'm having difficulty tracking this down.

Any help, of course, and as always, much appreciated.

---

Update:

I ended up using this, and it works how I wanted:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I came across this while looking for an answer the same question.

You can use:

`Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice())`

This formats the price (removes trailing zeros) and converts to the correct currency. Also works if the user changes their currency.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php echo $_product->getFormatedPrice(); ?>
```

it will format price according current store currency rules (see `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::format()` for more info).